# MongoDB - How to verify if a nested array item is contained in another nested array item on the same document?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

The idea here is to return an array of documents of the users' followers with  the information if this user is a friend of that follower or not.

So far I have:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a") } },
    { $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'followers',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 's_followers'
        }
    },
    { 
        $project: {
            "s_followers._id": 1,
            "s_followers.isFriend": {
                $in: ["s_followers.id",
                      { $setIntersection: ["$friends", "$followers"] }
                ]}
        }
    }
])
```

But the "s_followers.id" used in the $in operator doesn't seem to retrieve the _id information from the follower, so it always returns false.

When I use a ObjectId directly, I got the result I want:

```
"s_followers.isFriend": {
                    $in: [ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a"),
                          { $setIntersection: ["$friends", "$followers"] }
                    ]}
```

But I really need this ID to be a reference to the follower _id.

Expected result would be something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a"),
    "s_followers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5888687e56be8f172844d96f"),
            "isFriend" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5888ca27d79b8b03949a6e8c"),
            "isFriend" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

**UPD:** A different approach (maybe easier), would be to use the ID of the user that I have (the one used on $match), but I would still need to get the reference for the follower's follower array

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a") } },
    { $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'followers',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 's_followers'
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            "firstName": 1,
            "s_followers._id": 1,
            "s_followers.firstName": 1,
            "s_followers.followers": 1,
            "s_followers.isFriend": { $in: [ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a"), "$s_followers.followers"] }
        }
    }
])
```

**UPD2:** The user data structure (the part that matters)

```
{
  followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  friends: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
}
```

Comment: could you show your user data structure ?

Comment: sure! just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FOR VERSION 3.4.0+*

Ok, just got it, I'll post here the code and my understanding of it:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a") } },
    { $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'followers',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 's_followers'
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            "firstName": 1,
            "s_followers._id": 1,
            "s_followers.firstName": 1,
            "s_followers.followers": 1,
        }
    }, { 
        $unwind: "$s_followers"
    }, {
        $project: {
            "firstName": "$s_followers.firstName",
            "isFriend": { $in: [ObjectId("588877d82523b4395039910a"), "$s_followers.followers"] }
        }
    }
])
```

My understanding of it:

1. $match: match the user I'm intended to get the followers of.
2. $lookup: found each follower detail
3. $project: select the information I want to return, also get the follower list of each follower
4. $unwind: create a different document for each follower
5. With the array unwinded, I can refer to the follower's followers array, and find my object id in it :)

Comment: yes, for version 3.4.0. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Comment: I'll put that on the answer and mark yours as answer too ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my example use `followers friends` list to check current `user` is **friend** or not. as `{$arrayElemAt:["$s_followers.friends",0]}` if want to find in `followers` then can  use `"$s_followers.followers"`

You can try it.

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5714d190e6128b7e7f8d9008") } },
    {$unwind:"$followers"},
    { $lookup: {
            from: 'user',
            localField: 'followers',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 's_followers'
        }
    },
    {$project:{
        firstName:1,
        s_followers:{$arrayElemAt:["$s_followers",0]},
        isFriend:{$cond:[{
                $anyElementTrue:{
                  $map: {"input": {$arrayElemAt:["$s_followers.friends",0]},
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { "$eq": [ "$$el", "$_id" ] }
                  }
                }
              },true,false]}
        } 
    },
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        s_followers:{$push:{_id:"$s_followers._id",isFriend:"$isFriend"}}
        }
    }
])
```